# Grouping of elements based on sub element values

Tags: xml, xslt

Input xml:

```
<Points>
<point>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>20</y>
    <z>30</z>
</point>
<point>
    <x>30</x>
    <y>20</y>
    <z>10</z>
</point>
<point>
    <x>20</x>
    <y>10</y>
    <z>10</z>
</point>
<point>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>20</y>
    <z>40</z>
</point>
<point>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>10</y>
    <z>10</z>
</point>
<point>
    <x>30</x>
    <y>20</y>
    <z>10</z>
</point>
<point>
    <x>30</x>
    <y>20</y>
    <z>10</z>
</point>
</Points>
```

I want output like this:

```
<Details>
<Point2D>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>20</y>
    <count>2</count>
</Point2D>
<Point2D>
    <x>30</x>
    <y>20</y>
    <count>3</count>
</Point2D>
<Point2D>
    <x>20</x>
    <y>10</y>
    <count>1</count>
</Point2D>
<Point2D>
    <x>10</x>
    <y>10</y>
    <count>1</count>
</Point2D>
</Details>
```

Basically in output I am grouping the nodes which have same `x` and `y` with their counts.
I am discarding the `z` value in output. The grouping is done for the same values of two other nodes i.e. `x` and `y`.

I could not think of xsl code to get this output (with xslt 1.0).

Any solution? thanks.

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. Come back if you run into a **specific** problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming XSLT 3 it is as easy as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="Points">
    <Details>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="point" composite="yes" group-by="x, y">
        <Point2D>
          <xsl:sequence select="x, y"/>
          <count>{count(current-group())}</count>
        </Point2D>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Details>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks @Martin. Is it possible to have it with xslt 1.0?

Comment: @VineetDwivedi, sure, look into Muenchian grouping, there are tons of examples on Stackoverflow. On the other hand, using the various versions of Saxon (e.g. SaxonJS for XSLT 3 in the browser and with Node.js, SaxonC for XSLT 3 with C/C++/Python/PHP, SaxonJ for XSLT 3 with Java) there are lots of options to easily use XSLT 3 on most platforms without needing to rely on XSLT 1 from last century.

Comment: Good answer, and the comments. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MartinHonnen for the reference to Muenchian grouping. I was able to get it working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="point-by-xy" match="point" use="concat(x, '|', y)"/>
    <xsl:template match="point[generate-id() = generate-id(key('point-by-xy', concat(x, '|', y))[1])]">
        <point2D>
            <xsl:copy-of select="x"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="y"/>
            <count>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(key('point-by-xy', concat(x, '|', y)))"/>
            </count>
        </point2D>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="point"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Be careful: this produces only an XML fragment. The root Details element shown in your expected output is missing. You should start with a template matching Points.